# R - vectorized if for multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to calculate a heat stress index that depends on three distinct temperatures, following this expression:

[image]

My R implementation works OK for single temperature values:

```
# Set temperatures
Teff=34
Tcr=33
Tlim=40

# Apply conditions
if (Teff < Tcr) {
  hsa = 1
} else if (Teff >= Tcr & Teff < Tlim) {
  hsa = 1 - ((Teff - Tcr)/(Tlim - Tcr))
} else if (Teff >= Tlim) {
  hsa = 0
}

hsa
  [1] 0.8571429
```

However, if I try to calculate `hsa` for a range of `Teff`, like this:

```
Teff=seq(30,40,1)
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (Teff < Tcr) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Which apparently occurs because `if()` is not vectorized and therefore evaluates only the first element of the vector.

I learned about `ifelse()`, which is vectorized `if()`, but I'm not sure how it can be used for multiple conditions.

So, my question is: what would be an alternative, vectorized way to calculate my `hsa` index using vectors instead of scalars?

Comment: You can nest `ifelse` - example: `ifelse(x > 5, blah, ifelse(x > 3, yada, nada))`

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at `cut` if there are many ranges of values to deal with.

Comment: The problem with `ifelse` is that I don't have just `x` to evaluate. I have `x`, `y` and `z`, which makes nesting an intricate operation.

Comment: Try `pmin(pmax(0,1-(Teff-Tcr)/(Tlim-Tcr)),1)`.

Comment: @nicola thanks for your answer, but how do you relate the values 0 and 1 in your function to the first and last conditions of my expression? Just by using exclusion logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

It's the same function as above, but without the explicit `if` and `else`?

```
> Teff=seq(30,40,1)
> hsa<- 1*(Teff<Tcr) + (1 - (Teff - Tcr)/(Tlim - Tcr))*(Teff >= Tcr & Teff < Tlim)
> hsa
 [1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8571429 0.7142857 0.5714286 0.4285714 0.2857143 0.1428571 0.0000000
```

** Note that you can add `+ 0*(Teff>=Tlim)` in the end, but it wouldn't change anything, because the assigned value would be 0 anyways.

If you really want to use `ifelse`, then you have to nest them, so it should be something like this:

```
> hsa<- ifelse(Teff<Tcr, 1,
               ifelse(Teff >= Tcr & Teff < Tlim, 
               (1 - (Teff - Tcr)/(Tlim - Tcr)), 0))
> hsa
     [1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8571429 0.7142857 0.5714286 0.4285714 0.2857143 0.1428571 0.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the nested `ifelse`! It has the closest legibility compared to my original function!

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to think about this kind of problem is to think about "logical indexing".

[Example](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/vectorIndexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

@kandel is right. The better way is to use logical indexing.

Define the logical condition

```
idx <- iris$Species == "setosa"
new_iris = iris[idx,]
```

In your example, the following

```
if (Teff < Tcr) {
  hsa = 1
} else if (Teff >= Tcr & Teff < Tlim) {
         hsa = 1 - ((Teff - Tcr)/(Tlim - Tcr))
       } else if (Teff >= Tlim) {
hsa = 0
}
```

would translate to

```
idx <- Teff< Tcr
hsa[idx] <- 1 # and so on so forth
```